# Laravel Backpack File Manager - Cannot access shows Error 500

Tags: laravel-backpack, file-manager

[file-manager-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjNVm.png)

Backend Respond is not valid

In my local, works perfectly fine but in the server got the error. It shows error connector with a message "Call to undefined function set_time_limit()". Currently my server is using php 8.2.15.
Currently my version:

backpack/crud: "^5.0"
barryvdh/laravel-elfinder: "^0.5.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Call to undefined function set_time_limit()` typically occurs when the PHP function set_time_limit() is not available or disabled in your PHP configuration.

**Enable the Function:**
Open your PHP configuration file (php.ini) and ensure the `set_time_limit` function is not disabled. Look for the `disable_functions` directive and ensure that `set_time_limit` is not listed. If it is listed, remove it and restart your web server.